# Should I use 1.5" or 2" washing machine drain through multiple load bearing studs?

Tags: drain, structural, washing-machine, studs

We are working on adding a washer/dryer to a basement and tying the drain into an existing 3" main drain that is 10.5' away.

I'm concerned because the studs are load bearing - they hold up the floor joists for a small crawl space between the basement and the main floor (don't ask).

It seems the code for washing machine drains is 2", but also many folks have 1.5" drains without any issues. FWIW we'll be adding a small (apartment/24" wide) washer.

I'm wondering which option is better or if there is another approach:

1. Sticking with 2" drain, but using a [stud shoe](https://www.strongtie.com/miscellaneousconnectors_woodconnectors/ss_studshoe/p/ss). Can I use a stud shoe on all 9 studs in a row, or is there some limit where this is ok for 1 or 2, but not 9 in a row?
2. Use a 1.5" drain. Maybe I'd still need a stud shoe, but it makes me feel better that there is an extra 1/2"+ of original stud.

(There will also be a drain vent, which is not shown.)

[image]

Comment: Code does not have exceptions for "this would be inconvenient to install to code, so violating code is OK" - the normal method to avoid punching big holes in small studs is to run the pipe on the face of the wall, concealing it in a pipe chase or thickened wall if appearance factors require that.

Comment: Understood. Does installing the shoe studs with the 2" hole bring things up to code?

Comment: IRC 602.6(2)(exception) States that "the use of *approved* stud shoes is permitted where they are installed in accordance with the manufacturer's recommendations," which seem a bit hard to find at the site you linked for the stud shoe. But basically (that) code says that if Simpson says it's OK, it's OK, but you'll have to find chapter and verse from Simpson saying that it's OK, not a vague statement I can find that they are "code approved" without details about how many in a row you can use according to Simpson.

Comment: As a side note, the fact that you are installing a "small" washer is totally irrelevant. At some point in the future, someone else (maybe even future you) will install a bigger one. Therefore, code requires full compliance.

Answer (score 2):

This would take some investigation.

Can the washing machine drain pump trow water at a distance of 10 feet against the resistance of the 1.5 inch drain pipe. -Test it first before drilling lots of holes.

I read somewhere that the maximum hole in load bearing studs shall not exceed 40% of the stud width. That would exclude the 2 inch pipe on 3.5 inch stud.

If you determine you have to use 2 inch pipe the workaround that is you must use stud reinforcement as you mentioned.

I would in any case run the test without drilling to find out if the washing machine drain pump is mighty enough.

Comment: Thanks! I'm good with using 2", if the shoe studs keeps the wall/floor standing and up to code. The 1.5" was just an idea if that's not the case based on reading others' experience

Comment: @r_alanb here is the code article https://inspectapedia.com/structure/Wood-Joist-Stud-Boring-Notching-Codes.php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just run the pipe on the surface of the studs and fir the wall out and u won't need to damage any load bearing beams. It might be a lil more drywall work but if in the basement should be ok...Also then u can give pipe any slope that u need and use a 2" pipe and get max flow and no clogs...